# Bubble Sort in Python

Tags: python, arrays, sorting, bubble-sort

I have this `bubbleSort function` in python that works perfectly.

```
def bubbleSort(arr):
n = len(arr)

# Traverse through all array elements
for i in range(n):

    # Last i elements are already in place
    for j in range(0, n-i-1):

        # traverse the array from 0 to n-i-1
        # Swap if the element found is greater
        # than the next element
        if arr[j] > arr[j+1] :
            arr[j], arr[j+1] = arr[j+1], arr[j]
```

I am new to python and I am having trouble understanding the code below the if statement. How does `arr[j], arr[j+1] = arr[j], arr[j+1]` work?

Answer (score 2):

If you have come from other programming languages, you might not be familiar with the concept of assigning multiple variables with a single statement.

That is what is happening here.

Ii I  `x, y = 3, 4` then x will have the value 3 and y will have the value 4

in this case

`arr[j], arr[j+1] = arr[j+1], arr[j]` could be rewritten as

`arr[j] = arr[j+1]`
`arr[j+1] = arr[j]`

However, that would not swap the variables (which happens in a single statement, as @Dimitar says). It would really need to be rewritten as

`temp = arr[j]`
`arr[j] = arr[j+1]`
`arr[j+1] = temp`

I hope that you can see why

Answer (score 2):

In Python, tuples can be assigned directly. So the following code

```
arr[j], arr[j+1] = arr[j+1], arr[j]
```

if written as this, you would understand it better

```
(arr[j], arr[j+1]) = (arr[j+1], arr[j])
```

The code first creates a tuple containing `(arr[j+1], arr[j])`, then assign it correspondingly to `arr[j], arr[j+1]`, which effectively swaps the two elements.

In other languages, you have to write

```
temp = arr[j]
arr[j] = arr[j+1]
arr[j+1] = temp
```

which is just unnecessary in Python, given that you can assign tuples directly.

Answer (score 1):

Basically it is just swapping the values of `arr[j]` and `arr[j+1]`. `arr[j]` gets the value of `arr[j+1]` and `arr[j+1]` gets the value of `arr[j]`.

Answer (score -1):

The last line could also be written as:
`(arr[j], arr[j+1]) = (arr[j+1], arr[j])`

That means:

1. Pack elements `arr[j+1]` and `arr[j]` into an array.
2. Unpack them again.
3. Assign them to `arr[j]` and `arr[j+1]`.

The outer parentheses can be omitted in this case. What the lines does is basically swap elements `j` and `j+1` of `arr`.

A similar statement without array destructuring would be:

```
tmp = arr[j]
arr[j] = arr[j+1]
arr[j+1] = tmp
```

Comment: I believe parentheses here is better than brackets.

Comment: Possibly, however, it works with brackets as well.

Comment: But brackets creates arrays, not tuples.

Comment: True, and I admit that you should use tuples over arrays whenever possible, but I still stand with my point that they still work for destructring. (I'm used to brackets from JavaScript.)